# How much the propelled objects cause damage in Half-Life 2: Deathmatch?

Tags: half-life-2-deathmatch

Just like in the singleplayer, in [Half-Life 2: Deathmatch](https://store.steampowered.com/app/320/HalfLife_2_Deathmatch/) the gravity gun can be used to grab and launch objects at enemies. However, unless I'm suffering from severe lag (my ping is reasonable, around 50) the objects don't have collision with players, even tables fly through players seemingly intact. Perhaps this is how the multiplayer was designed to accommodate the dial-up connections of 2004? Do all thrown props still cause damage?

Because the game doesn't support bots there's no easy way to test offline. Also the vast majority of active servers seem to be running mods and to my knowledge there's no way to filter them out.

Comment: Physics objects certainly used to deal damage this way when I played back in 2004/2005. I don't know what's changed in the intervening 15 years though. I would guess server mods are changing it because it was too easy to hold up a table and block bullets, then kill someone with it.